# If $\int_0^x|a(t)|dt<\infty$ and $s(t)=\int_0^ta(x)dx$ then $\int_0^x|s(t)|dt<\infty$?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration

Let $a(t)$ be a function defined on $(0,\infty)$ satisfying $\int_0^x|a(t)|dt<\infty$ for all $x\in\mathbb{R^+}.$

Set $s(t)=\int_0^ta(x)dx$. Is it always true that

$\int_0^x|s(t)|dt<\infty$ for all $x\in\mathbb{R^+}$.

Or are there any counter example does not satisfy this property?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it's true. If $x \in \Bbb R^+$, then

\begin{align}\int_0^x |s(t)|\, dt &= \int_0^x \left\lvert \int_0^t a(u)\, du\right\rvert\, dt \le \int_0^x \int_0^t |a(u)|\, du\, dt = \int_0^x \int_u^x |a(u)|\, dt\, du\\ &= \int_0^x (x - u)|a(u)|\, du \le x \int_0^x |a(u)|\, du < \infty.\end{align}

Comment: $\leq x \int_0^x |a(u)|\, du < \infty$. Is $x$ in here does not problem for boundedness of this expression since $x\in \Bbb R^+$?

Comment: I don't fully understand the question, but the reason $x\int_0^x |a(u)|\, du < \infty$ is because $\int_0^x |a(u)|\, du < \infty$ by assumption and $0 < x < \infty$.

Comment: thank you you get my question right.